# Search from multiple table in php

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a site in which I want to allow the users to search as multiple keyword as a string.
Suppose I have 3 tables: `Subject`, `Level` and `users`. If user search for `Primary Computer Science Male Test`,
I Want to show the results from joining three tables. That is `Primary` from table `Level` and `computer Science` from table `Subjects` and remaining from the `user` table. If the user search for `computer science` just show the results from table `Subject`. How it possible using MYSQL query?

Comment: I think this is the domain of natural language processing. I don't have extensive knowledge on this.

Answer (score 0):

User input:

```
Computer Primary
```

Compose Query in this way:

```
select * 
from Subject as s join level as l on s.id = l.subject_id 
   join users as u on u.subject_id = s.id
where 
   l.name = :firstterm or s.name = :firstterm or u.name = :firsterm or
   l.name = :secondterm or s.name = :secondterm or u.name = :secondterm
```

Where :firsterm is the first user input term and :secondterm is the scond once